# 自作iOSアプリのADP無しでの配布について

Tags: ios, xcode

アプリ開発初心者です。自作iOSアプリを開発し、有料ライセンスは使わずに友人に使ってもらおうと思い、直接繋げてもらおうと思っているのですが友人にその話をしたところ他人のmacにiPhoneを繋げるのが心配と言われました。調べてみても実際直接繋げて配布する人がいるようですが...特に、

・iPhoneで他人のコンピュータを信頼した時に情報(写真など)が漏れてしまうのか
・アプリの使用の為に人のmacにAppleIDとパスワードを入力することは普通なのか

が知りたいです。簡単な質問かもしれませんが回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

> ・iPhoneで他人のコンピュータを信頼した時に情報(写真など)が漏れてしまうのか

今はわかりませんが、ちょっと前までは他人のiPhoneを接続した瞬間に、iPhoneに保存されている写真たちが画面いっぱいにプレビューされてしまうという便利（？）機能がありました。実際これで気まずい思いをした経験が何度かあります。
また、ここで「同期」を押せばもちろん写真や音楽は他人のMacに同期されてしまいますよ。このあたりを気にされるのなら、他人のMacには自分のiPhoneを繋がないことをオススメします。

> ・アプリの使用の為に人のmacにAppleIDとパスワードを入力することは普通なのか

これは聞いたことがありません。他人のパソコンで自分のID/Passを入力することは普通に考えてリスクがあることは言わずもがなだと思います。